# iPhone uiWebView - 'didImageWasClicked' like event?

Tags: iphone, html, image, uiwebview, click

Newbie Question.

I have a UIWebView that I push HTML code into. In the HTML code is an image. Is there a way to get informed that image #3 or image with name 'bob' was touched ? Some event like 'didImageWasClickedAndHereIsTheIDOfTheClickedThingy' perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way to do this that is directly supported by `UIWebView`, but there is a slightly hacky way.

Add JavaScript `onclick` handlers to your images that do something like this:

```
function (imgElement) {
    document.location = "http://myapp/didClick/" + imgElement.id;
}
```

When the user taps the image, a request will me made, which can be intercepted by your app by implementing `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` on the `UIWebView`'s delegate.